# Как в с++ передать в функцию обработчик, чтоб он не был стеснен определенным числом аргументов и определенными типом возвращаемого значения?

Tags: c++, анонимная-функция

Как в с++ передать в функцию обработчик, чтоб он не был стеснен определенным числом аргументов и определенными типом возвращаемого значения? Таким же образом, как мы можем передать в std::thread функцию с любым числом и типом аргументов и любым возвращаемым значением

Comment: Кусочек кода, демонстрирующий то, что и как Вы хотите вызывать, был бы полезен.

Comment: в подобных случаях почти всегда ответ шаблоны.

Comment: если вы хотите вызывать эту функцию, то никак. Способы передачи аргументов и возвращаемого значения зависят конкретно от типов. Сузьте пожалуйста ваши желания и приведите **пример** попроще.